# helm yaml error - found unexpected ':'

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a **Deployment** that I'm writing in a **helm** template and am getting an error when including part of a **command** line:

```
command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
              printf "-instances=%s=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306" .Values.sqlproxy.instanceName,
              "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
```

on linting the deployment (`helm lint .`) I get the following error:

> error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 25: found unexpected ':'

If I remove the part of the **command:** `=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306` the deployment lints fine but I need it :)

Is there a way of escaping the colons?

Or should I rewrite the **command** array?

I've uploaded the complete yaml to a gist: [sqlproxy-deployment.yaml](https://gist.github.com/theGC/f04ba400d2d622a746470c79cee611c4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap template directives in `{{ }}`

```
"{{ printf "-instances=%s=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306" .Values.sqlproxy.instanceName }}"
```

Comment: hey, wrapping it made no difference so I'd assume that the issue is with the array itself.

Comment: No, the array is fine. I'm guessing you forgot quotes around the entire function call.
`"{{ printf "-instances=%s=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306" .Values.sqlproxy.instanceName }}"`